# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException cannot take "cause" in constructor

Tags: java, exception

Java `Exceptions` usually have a (among others) a constructor that can take a Throwable cause, so that when rethrowing an exception one can give the original exception and it will appear in the log as

```
com.stacktrace.from.application.exception...
Caused by
net.stacktrace.of.code.throwing.original.exception...
```

However `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` has only `()`, `(int index)` or `(String s)`. No constructor accepts a cause!!

Looking at the type hierarchy it seems that both `Exception` and `RuntimeException` are fine, but already `IndexOutOfBoundsException` has lost the `(String s, Throwable cause)` constructor.

I know that constructors are not inherited, but **WHY** would one not have a similar one for `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: What kind of cause would you pass to those Exceptions ?

Comment: The problem in the code I was looking at was that StringIndexOutOfBoundsException was used as an application exception, where the exception was caught and a new instance of StringIndexOutOfBoundsException was thrown with some more data in the exception message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IndexOutOfBoundsException`is not the only `Throwable` without the cause parameter constructor. For example`NullPointerException` is also the case. I'm sure there is more. The explanation is simple these are the root causes. They are not caused by another exceptions, but thrown directly by JVM. Either programmer's mistake or external source is causing them.

You may of course use constructor with description of the exception when creating and throwing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that exceptions that are not supposed to have a cause do not have a constructor with a Throwable argument. You still can add a cause to any exception through `initCause` method though :

```
    try{
        "aaa".substring(10);
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        e.initCause(new RuntimeException("some cause exception"));
        throw e;
    }
```